# Cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-tabs

I am using jquery tabs, my home.jsp has this..

```
<div id = "tabs">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="page1" class="menu-text" >Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2" class="menu-text" >Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3" class="menu-text" >Page3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page4" class="menu-text" >Page4</a></li>
                <li><a href="page4" class="menu-text" >Page5</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Home.jsp also has,

```
<script>
          $(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                         if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
                              event.preventDefault();
                              return false;
                            }
                         ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                         ui.panel.html(
                         "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " );
                         });
                        ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
                            ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
                        });
                  } 
                 });

             }); 

    </script>
```

I am using Spring MVC, the pages, page 1-5 are mapped to jsp's. Now my first page Page1, loaded in tab1, has a button which should take me to tab2:page2. I am using

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option","active",1 );
```

in the $.click() of page2.js. When I click the button I get the error,

```
Cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
```

Please help !

My page1.js has

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $today = new Date();
    $yesterday = new Date($today);  
    $yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);
    var $dd = $yesterday.getDate();
    var $mm = $yesterday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var $yyyy = $yesterday.getFullYear();
    if($dd<10){$dd='0'+dd;} 
    if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm;} 
    $yesterday = $yyyy+'-'+$mm+'-'+$dd;
    $("#yestDate").html($yesterday);
  });
$('#button').click(function() { 

    $("#tabs").tabs("option","active",1 );
    /*if($('#tabs').hasClass('ui-tabs')){$("#tabs").tabs("option","active",1 );}*/
    /*$("#tabs").tabs({active:1});*/
    /*$( ".selector" ).tabs( "refresh" );
    $("#tabs").tabs("load",1);*/
});
```

I also tried pre-loading all tabs in case its a problem, but $.load is also giving the same error. What initialization is this !! Is there any alternative approach to what I want.

Comment: whether the tabs are there in the home page or in the second page

Comment: The tabs are there on the home page

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML and code? It appears to work fine in this test JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YTLHx/

Comment: The list and script makes most of my home, summary has another list, and page1.js has code that I am pasting as edit. Please explain the error if possible.

Comment: I didn't get your fiddle, what are the pages referring to ? I have tried doing this with divs and it works. I don't know if there is a problem on using JSP's

Comment: The error simply means that you did not call `.tabs({})` constructor on the element but you are invoking `.tabs("somemethod")`.

Comment: But I did call the .tabs({})!!

Comment: Basically, I have a JSP page having tabs which load other JSP's, the js file is referred to in page1.jsp. How do I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try put $("#tabs").tabs(); first